accidently put wrong deposit address
Accidently missclicked on keyboard and have deleted one last digit (1) of the deposit address on phantom wallet (withdraw adress to my other wallet) to my other wallet when sending solana and have never recieved the money. Is it possible to somehow get it back? Please.

I don’t think it’s possible to get it back.
Next time when you try to send assets to another wallet make sure to send an small
Amount first to avoid mistakes like that.
I hope you find a way to get your money back
